# Windows 10 mail: how to display all accounts in the left pane?

Tags: windows-10

I'm migrating from Outlook 2010 to Mail for Windows 10, but am struggling to get all my email accounts in the left column, as I was used to in Outlook.

At the moment, I have to manually switch to each individual account by clicking "Accounts", then clicking on the account name.

**Is it possible to have all the accounts on top of each other in the left pane?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a recent update, the Mail app has been improved and now always shows the accounts in the left pane. Great!

Answer (score 1):

I have used the Mail app alot, and I was not able to find an option in the Settings, the registry, or the internet. I belive is not possible to have all the accounts on top of each other in the left pane.